# How to add mutliple QnA bots to Enterprise Assistant?

Tags: azure, botframework, bot-framework-composer

Our teams create individual bots for themselves and now we want to integrate them into the Enterprise Assistant.
What I need help with is Multi Bot Orchestration.
Has anyone been able to do this efficiently?
Basically, the user asks a question in the Enterprise Assistant and then the bot gets the answer from the respective child/skill QnA bot.

I am able to add skills like calendar, people, SAP, etc. but dealing with QnA bots is proving to be an impossible challenge.

Comment: `"But dealing with QnA bots is proving to be an impossible challenge."` what made this challenging? what are you fighting with?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Most of the examples of skill bots are with respect to some particular feature e.g. weather, sap, service now, etc. and for these, it's easy to add intents to the root bot. But we have multiple QnA bots and want to add them to the root bot.

Answer (score 0):

To create a multi bot orchestration, we need to include multiple levels of dispatchers, pipelines for exception handling and fallbacks. It needs an expert system type agent who can handle multiple NLP models. A chat bot is designed based on NLP modelling. The NLP implementation will be depending on number of operations that enterprise application will handle. The following are the different NLP models required to handle a perfect enterprise application.

1. General QnA
2. Billing information
3. Calendar
4. Leave Planning
5. Employee storage disk
6. On demand service to the clients
7. Fault tolerance
8. Saving the QnA pattern of chat between bot and human
9. Calculating the accuracy
10. Taking users own request and performing NLP
    like this we have so many requirements to implement a Bot. All the models will be trained and connected to the dispatcher.

The following are the things followed in bot orchestration.

It consists of 5 different implementations:

1. Ingress Pipeline
2. Egress Pipeline
3. Dispatcher
4. Exception pipeline
5. Fallback pipeline
   Ingress Pipeline:

The ingress pipeline will be detection few things like

1. Language detect and translate
2. Entity recognition
3. User input redaction
   Egress Pipeline:

the following are requirement and operations in egress pipeline

1. 3rd party tools for analytics
2. Managed responses (default responses)
3. Data service redaction
   Dispatcher:
   The dispatcher will be having two different implementations.
4. Policies and rules,
5. NLU (Natural Language Understanding) strategy.

Policies and Rules

The policies and rules of the organization must be trained to the model. Because, if the user is asking for the financial status of the orgzanition, the bot must understand the policies and rules it must follow in order to answer for the question.

Natual Language Understanding

Natural Language Understanding (NLU)  — The computer’s ability to understand what we say. The context what user is typing in his/her own words is the procedure of NLU.

The dispatcher will be communicating with the egress pipeline and ingress pipeline as it is the parent handler of all the operations and model training results.

To address the exceptions and rollbacks, we need to have exception handlers who are also expert system agents. An agent is having some expertise in handling the exceptions.

Example:

Question: Give the details of pithon projects of this monthh.

Handled Exceptions: In the above question "python" spelt like "pithon" and "month" was spelt like "monthh". NLP and NLU have to understand these cluases and have to handle in exception of mis-spelt words.

The following link can explain in detailed architecture of Multi-bot orchestration.

https://servisbot.com/multi-bot-orchestration-architecture/